# java layertools extract does not preserve timestamps

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-buildkit

I am using the layered jar file approach [1] for optimizing our Docker image build times.  I have noticed that the jar files that are extracted from the following command do not preserve the timestamp of the individual jar files that get extracted.

```
java -Djarmode=layertools -jar my-uber-jar.jar extract
```

If I run the above command, check the timestamps on the extracted files, and then re-run the command and recheck the timestamps they are always updated to the current time.

example:

```
$ java -Djarmode=layertools -jar my-uber-jar.jar  extract 
$ ls -l dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-*
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   327K Oct  1 09:23 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   204K Oct  1 09:23 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   490K Oct  1 09:23 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff    60K Oct  1 09:23 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   2.1M Oct  1 09:23 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
```

... wait ~5 minutes ...

```
$ java -Djarmode=layertools -jar my-uber-jar.jar extract 
$ ls -l dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-*
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   327K Oct  1 09:29 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   204K Oct  1 09:29 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   490K Oct  1 09:29 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff    60K Oct  1 09:29 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 legacy  staff   2.1M Oct  1 09:29 dependencies/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
```

The reason this is an issue for me is that I am attempting to use Docker buildkit [2] optimizations to reduce the amount of build context sent to a remote Docker daemon.  The idea behind using the layered jar file approach and Docker buildkit was to avoid sending any dependency jar files to the remote docker daemon unless they changed in some way.  Docker buildkit seems to notice the changed timestamps and then sends all of the files over to the remote server even though a checksum on those files is identical to the previous build.  I have confirmed that if I just do the build without re-extracting the files that very little data is sent to the remote Docker daemon.

Using the layered jar file approached worked well for reducing the amount of data sent on a `docker push` but our workflow requires a docker build on a remote server (via IntelliJ's remote docker build feature)

That leads me to my questions:

a) is it possible to extract the layers while preserving the timestamps?

b) is it possible to make docker buildkit look at checksums instead of timestamps?

[1] https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/creating-efficient-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3
[2] https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to extract the layers while preserving the timestamps?

Spring Boot's layer tools doesn't support this at the moment. It sounds like a useful feature to add, though, and I think it should probably be the default behaviour. We already take care to preserve the timestamps when creating the jar so I think it makes sense to preserve them during extraction as well.

Please [open a Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) and we'll take a look.

Comment: I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28167)

Comment: The github issue has been fixed and released to version 2.5.6 of spring boot.   I have re-tested it and can confirm that it addresses the issue and enables BuildKit to send only the files that have updated timestamps to the remote Docker daemon.